# Spring MVC partially object binding

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

As far I know, Spring MVC allows to bind objects like that:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public void doSmth(MyObject obj) {
// All MyObject's fields are filled now
}
```

But does there exists an elegant solution, which allows to bind the only specific fields?

For example, class `User` may possible contain private information such as registration timestamp which could be easily replaced by 3d-party side in case of using common object binding.

So needed is smth like:

```
class User {

   public String nick; <-- wanna bind this
   public String pass; <-- and this
   public Calendar timestamp; <-- but not this
   ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with data binder initialization.

For example using `@InitBinder` annotation in the controller:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  binder.setDisallowedFields("timestamp"); 
}
```